EasyMDE / Codemirrror "blur" event
I would like to have an event "on edit finished" when the user leaves the easyMDE editor. I have added a "blur" event, the problem is that it is also fired when the user clicks on a button on the toolbar, here an example:


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/easymde/dist/easymde.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/easymde/dist/easymde.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
<script>
const easyMDE = new EasyMDE();
  
   easyMDE.codemirror.on("blur", () => {
            console.log("BLUR EVENT ");
        });
  
</script>



Any suggestion is appreciated. Thx.

you could do .on("blur", (editor, event) => console.log(editor, event)) and see whether you can match on anything...

ok, I could check if event.relatedTarget.parentElement.parentElement.className=='EasyMDEContainer. Not so nice, but effective... thx
